# I need to monitor an adult relative's internet useage without his/her knowledge

Tags: website, history, surveillance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to track websites that have been visited?](https://superuser.com/questions/52181/how-to-track-websites-that-have-been-visited)

I need to monitor an adult relative's internet usage without his or her
knowledge. The laptop I need to watch is a Mac, about 1 year old. Our computers are not tied together in any way. Can this be done?

Comment: Theoretically, it can be done. Practically, there are technical, ethical and legal implications.

Comment: Wow that's illegal in most places...

Comment: define “usage”. Do you mean bandwidth usage or sites visited?

Comment: Synetech inc:  I mean sites visited, thnx

Answer (score 5):

There are a few questions related to this topic already:

- [How can I monitor network traffic in an all Mac home network?](https://superuser.com/questions/149974/how-can-i-monitor-network-traffic-in-an-all-mac-home-network)
- [Software for measuring internet traffic?](https://superuser.com/questions/75083/software-for-measuring-internet-traffic) (for Windows)
- [Application for monitoring all applications that are using the internet in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/50515/application-for-monitoring-all-applications-that-are-using-the-internet-in-mac-os)
- [On Mac OS X how can I monitor what is using my internet connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/7184/on-mac-os-x-how-can-i-monitor-what-is-using-my-internet-connection)

The answers to these questions might help you, though I'm not sure if any fit your needs exactly.

It's not clear from your question, but when you say "our computers are not tied together in any way", are you implying that you want some way to get the software onto your relative's computer without having direct access to the laptop? If so, be forewarned that a) that is *very* difficult, b) is almost certainly illegal in most jurisdictions, and c) is *not* something which we will help you with on Super User.

Regardless of how you are attempting to do this, please make sure you consider the legal and and ethical ramifications of spying on somebody, regardless of your intentions. Even if you have access to the computer, there very well may still be laws prohibiting the installation of tracking software without their permission.

Comment: nhinkle, thanks.  I do have access but the user is savvy enough to delete the history after every use.  My concern is for the well being of my relative, who is most likely not doing something illegal, but i worry about websites that are damaging to my relative's well being.  if I could install something that tracks websites visited, and it confirms my fears, i could intervene and offer help.  if confronted without evidence, my relative will likely simply deny.  The tracker would have to be something invisible to the user.  I know how this sounds, but i am deeply concerned, enough to seek help.